# El código de Go es mas lento que Javascript? o mi implementación es incorrecta?

Tags: javascript, go, rendimiento

Estaba probando el siguiente algoritmo, y se me ocurrió comparar los tiempos entre javascript y go, y me llevé una sorpresa que la función de go tardaba más tiempo, para medir el tiempo en go utilicé time y para javascript utilicé Date().
Al momento de medir el tiempo que tardan en completarse cada función la de Go tarda entre 2 a 3s más, no creo que Go sea más lento. Si alguien me podría ayudar con esto, se lo agradecería. Lo probé con 10000

Código Go

```
func pri(num int) int{
    var z int 
    var n int
    var primos_por_mostrar int
    primos_por_mostrar = num
    z = 0
    n = 2
    for ;primos_por_mostrar > 0; {

        /* determinar si n es primo */
        var es_primo bool
        es_primo = true
        for d := 2; d < n; d++ {
            if n % d == 0 {
                es_primo = false
                break
            }
        }

        /* mostrar el numero
         * y actualizar el contador */
        if es_primo {
            z+=n
            primos_por_mostrar--;
        }
        n++
    }
    return z

}
```

Código Javascript Es ejecutado desde el navegador

```
function pri(num){
    z=0;
    primos_por_mostrar=num;

    n = 2;
    while (primos_por_mostrar > 0) {

        /* determinar si n es primo */
        es_primo = 1;
        for (d = 2; d < n; ++d) {
            if (n % d == 0) {
                es_primo = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        /* mostrar el numero
         * y actualizar el contador */
        if (es_primo) {
            z+=n;
            primos_por_mostrar--;
        }
        n++;
    }
    return z;

}
```

Comment: Ambos serían mas rápidos si usaras hilos.

Comment: ¿Con qué compilas el programa en go? ¿Con el compilador oficial de go, gccgo, otro...? Con gccgo puedes pasar opciones de optimización a la hora de compilar el código para obtener código más eficiente

Comment: @abrahamhs Gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: @ordago Estoy utilizando el compilador por defecto de go

Comment: puedes agregar el bloque de codigo donde haces tu medicion?, que pruebas ejecutaste?, como las ejecutaste? etc

Comment: como ejecutas tu codigo go ? si lo haces directamente con go run, debes considerar el tiempo de compilado antes de hacer la ejecución, lo ideal siempre es hacer el compilado y probar ya sea el exe o bin generado :) 

Igual como mencionan hay flags especiales que te ayudan a optimizar a la hora de compilar como menciona ordago